# Create an array from an associative array using one of its value in a key value pair

Tags: php, arrays, associative-array

I've a following associative array named $data. Here is some same key value pairs

```
 Array
   (
      [0] => Array
      (
        [id] => 1
        [config_id] => 31
        [language] => "English"
      )

      [1] => Array
      (
        [id] => 2
        [config_id] => 33
        [language] => "English"
      )
      [2] => Array
      (
        id] => 3
        [config_id] => 32
        [language] => "French"
      )

   )
```

And i wanted to convert this array as

```
Array
   (
      ["English"] => Array(
       [0]=> Array
        (
        [id] => 1
        [config_id] => 31
       )

       [1] => Array
       (
        [id] => 2
        [config_id] => 33
       )
      )
      ["French"] => 
      Array(
       [0]=> Array
        (
        [id] => 3
        [config_id] => 32
        )
      )
     )
   )
```

I need the language as key in the output array,Can anyone help me out to resolve this issue? Thanks in advance.
I tried the following code, but printed the last array value only

```
     $arry = array();
     foreach ($data as $val) {
        
        $arry[$val->language]["id"] =  $val->id;
        $arry[$val->language]["config_id"] =  $val->config_id;
     }
```

Comment: Where are you stuck? What have you tried? There is lots of info and previous questions here and elsewhere about manipulating arrays. We're happy to help people, but you generally need to show a good-faith attempt to figure it out yourself first. We're volunteers, it's our free time, we don't need to solve stuff if it could be answered by a bit of prior research and effort. "can anyone help me" isn't a valid question on SO - you need to ask something specific / focused about an actual coding problem, not just a request for someone else to write it all for you.

Comment: @ADyson sorry, i referred previous questions and tried some code, but printed the last array value only, that's why i hesitate to posting tried code

Comment: You should always post your attempt, don't hesistate. It helps because a) it shows you genuinely tried it yourself before asking for others to help, and b) in many cases the code will be almost right and just needs a small fix - which is exactly what has happened here in the end. That's more efficient than someone re-writing it all from the beginning. It also creates a more focused question, which is likely to be more helpful for people experiencing the same sort of issue in future. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are nearly there, just need to make the new array all in one go and just use the `$arry[$val->language][]` to create a new sub array under that new or existing language key.

Also `$data` is an array or arrays not an array of objects so the addressing of the items was wrong.

```
$arry = array();
foreach ($data as $val) {
    $arry[$val->language][] =  ['id' => $val['id'], 'config_id' => $val['config_id']];
}
```